# Get selected value from dropdown while bininding it with razor foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvvm

I am binding dropdown like below

```
<select id="example1">
     @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
       <option value=@item.Id data-image=@item.Document_Page_URL>Image</option>
      }
</select>
```

Actually client is using some plugins as you can see data-image in option tag this is the only option to bind images and i have done that,
now i want to get selected value from this dropdown, it would be better if i could post (using searlize methode) value using my ViewModel please help ,
**NOTE** I am newbie in MVC so please ignore if i am wrong any where in question, Also if any one can suggest me a method in mvc to bind images to @Html.Dropdownfor() will be appreciated

Comment: How do you plan sending the data to your server? Via post?

Comment: by using seralization

Comment: Thats not binding! Why are you not using the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` method? And your not even giving the element a `name` attribute so using `.serialize()` would ignore it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok i will use name attribute as well but the reason for not using @Html.DropDownListFor() is i am bind images with this dropdown whic are not allowed in @Html.DropDownListFor() as per my research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Html.DropDownListFor()` and set `value="@item.Id"`

Comment: you can use `data-picture` or `data-image` ex data-image="url"